# AngularJS: multiple Factory Instances any prototypical inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, factory

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mccJ1uXX3CHYH134PafU?p=preview) (Probably explains the issue without my description below)

I have the following construct in my Angular-App (also see [Angular Services](http://www.reonomy.com/angular-services) for references):

I use a Factory `BaseService` which implements several functions. I define these functions on the `BaseService.prototype` so that they are public later on (also refer to the link above).

Private variables are declared using the `var` keyword.

This Factory is instanciated by multiple services, where each service provides its own values for the initialization. However a factory is still a singleton, so the second time it gets initialized this overwrites the private variables used by the first Service.

**Is there a best practice to prevent this?**

**If there isn't - can you suggest a solution (even if it requires to remove the private variables)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `this` instead of a global variable, [updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/56oXXvl75zH4mTfAqMsd?p=preview).

Comment: in the constructor i stored `this` to a variable `service` because `this` refers to the wrong context when used in other objects, nested functions or angular.forEach loops. Obviously this does not solve my issue because the `service` variable points to the wrong location too after the next constructor call. How can I reliably call the functions of my factory when i can neither access the context via `this`, nor store my context in a variable?

Comment: @HW I don't know exactly what point you're trying to make but looping works fine, see this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/56oXXvl75zH4mTfAqMsd?p=preview, both angular.forEach and ngRepeat work fine

Comment: I used `angular.foreach` in a different context (you can pass the context as third parameter). Thus using `angular.foreach` within the factory but in a different context prevents me from calling the functions of my factory. It wasn't necessary though and i could rewrite my code - seemed to be bad style anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a static private variable, which contains private data for each factory instance.  When the factory is instantiated, its instance is assigned a unique id (also a static private variable), and that unique id is also the key into the data array.

```
  var privateVars = {};   // has contained private vars for each instance
  var baseServiceId=0;    // unique id assigned to each instance

  var BaseService = function(initval){
    this.baseServiceId = ++baseServiceId;
    privateVars[this.baseServiceId] = {"storedVal":initval};
  };

  BaseService.prototype.plusone = function(){
    pv = privateVars[this.baseServiceId].storedVal;
    privateVars[this.baseServiceId].storedVal = pv+1;
  };
  BaseService.prototype.getVal = function(){
    return privateVars[this.baseServiceId].storedVal;
  };
```

Here is the updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/56oXXvl75zH4mTfAqMsd?p=preview

Comment: seems a bit hacky, but i like it. Way better than not having private variables ;)

Comment: lol, it is a bit hacky, especially for your usage.  I came up with it when I was creating a factory that I intended to also use as a searchable cache.  I didn't I actually need to keep the data private, i just needed a way to search through all instances!